# Multiple protocol conformace in enum doesn't work

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, swift4.2

I am trying to conform multiple protocols with single protocol in the enum. If I type them separately it work. However, if I try to combine them in a single protocol it doesn't work.

I have following enum

```
enum Theme:Int,CaseIterable,CustomStringConvertible {
  case light
  case dark

var description: String {
    switch self {
    case .light:
        return "Light Theme"
    case .dark:
        return "Dark Theme"
    }
}

var backgroundColor: Color {
    switch self {
    case .light:
        return .white
    case .dark:
        return .black
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to convert its conformance to protocol by this

```
public protocol ThemeProvider where T.RawValue == Int {
    associatedtype T:RawRepresentable,CaseIterable,CustomStringConvertible
}
```

and changed enum definition to `enum Theme:ThemeProvider`

However it says 'Theme' does not conform to expected type 'ThemeProvider' What is the proper way to add protocol to enum?

PS: Above code is Swift 4.2 and uses new protocol called `CaseIterable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the enum Definition from `enum Theme: Int, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible {` to `enum Theme:ThemeProvider {` does not make Theme automatically have a `T`, which is required by ThemeProvider.

And if you add `typealias T = Theme` then the Theme enum does still not have `Int, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible`, cause `typealias T = Theme` does not make any type(Theme here) conform any protocol.

That's why `enum Theme: Int, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible, ThemeProvider { typealias T = Theme ...` is required to make Theme conform to ThemeProvider.

What you probably want is `enum Theme: Int, ThemeProvider {` where ThemeProvider is `public protocol ThemeProvider: RawRepresentable, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible {}`.

More can't be said without any example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I solved it by defining the protocol like this `public protocol ThemeProvider:RawRepresentable,CaseIterable,CustomStringConvertible where RawValue == Int {
}` and defining the theme like `enum MDTheme:Int,ThemeProvider {` solved the issue.